# How can I add unique integer value as a new column to a spark streaming data frame that has multiple sink

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, uuid

I am working on a pyspark streaming project where we receive XML files from a Kafka topic and write extracted elements into several different snowflake tables. Stakeholders made a request to include a unique integer field (unique across all runs of the job) in all tables but the field value should match in each table for the same XML message.

i.e.

```
Table1

XML_file   Colum_x   Int_Id
xml1        valuea     1
xml2        valueb     2
```

```
Table2

XML_file   Colum_y   Int_Id
xml1        valuec     1
xml2        valued     2
```

All of the target tables get written in parallel with a method similar to below

```
df1.writeStream.foreachBatch(stream_writer).start()
df2.writeStream.foreachBatch(stream_writer).start()
...

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

Before sharding the streaming dataframe when I add the requested column using a UDF, all tables get written with different UUIDs for the same XML file, making it impossible to match across tables.

```
uuidUdf = F.udf(lambda: str(uuid.uuid4().int), StringType())
df_values_parsed = df_values_parsed1.withColumn("Integer_ID", uuidUdf())
```

If I use the spark uuid function without a udf, then all rows get written with the same value.

```
df_values_parsed = df_values_parsed1.withColumn("TRADE_ID", F.lit(str(uuid.uuid4())))
```

How can I meet this requirement in spark streaming?